# Salesfroce single Email send class

Tags: salesforce

I had used this class to send an email. but now its not working. i am new for salesforce.

```
List<String> Address = new List<String>();
Address.add('Email address is here');
```

mail object code is as following :

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> allApplicantAttachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment applicantAttachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
PageReference pdf = new pagereference('/apex/gernerateInvoicePdf?Id=a12m00000014ADN');
mail.setToAddresses(Address); 
mail.setSubject('test');
mail.sethtmlBody('hello');
Blob b = pdf.getContent();
//mail.setBody(b);
applicantAttachment.setBody(b);
applicantAttachment.setFileName('test.html');
allApplicantAttachments.add(applicantAttachment);
mail.setFileAttachments(allApplicantAttachments);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is proper and it works for me. You might setup an email log as mentioned  [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs.htm&language=en_US) to see if the email is not getting delivered?

Sreenish

Comment: thank you for your response. now i am getting email.

Answer (score 0):

At the end you are trying to send a to a new list. using:

```
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

try adding your mails to a list first like this :

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<String> addresses = new List<String>();                
                    addresses.add(emailAddress);
                    mail.setToAddresses(addresses);
                    mail.setPlainTextBody(convertList(contactList));
                    //Add to list then call send with full list
                    mailToSend.add(mail);
                Messaging.sendEmail(mailToSend);
```